# how to print barcode label from browser (reactjs) using printer wincode c342c

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, zpl

Anyone have experience print from client side (javascript / reactjs) to printer wincode c342c. I have install qz.io library, so my javascript can access the client's printer. 
I have tried to print pdf as base64 to Microsoft print to pdf printer and it works.
I have tried to connect the wincode 342c printer from my javascript and it works. 
What don't works for me is sending command to printer from the printer utilities apps and send raw print command (generic/zpl) from javascript using qz.io.

I prefer to send raw command to printer than getting pdf (base64) from backend and then pass to the qz.io library, because i think it will be faster in raw printing mode than pixel printing. And to reduce backend processing when a lot of clients requesting at the same time.
Please correct me if i'm wrong.

If anyone can throw some englightment will be very appreciated.

Comment: What driver is installed for the printer? Can you print ZPL from notepad to the printer?

Comment: hi @EdHayes3 the driver is wincode driver.. so to test print zpl from notepad, i just paste the zpl command to printer and print ? and it supposed to print as raw commnad not text ?

Comment: hi, have you found a solution ? I would like to print a label by using a label printer from ReactJS... or are they have the same procedure with printing A4 ?

Comment: please try jsprintmanager library @wasilikoslow and please make sure your printer is supported by the library. i have tried honeywell and it works well

Answer (score 0):

Change the driver to "Generic" manufacturer, and "Generic / Text Only" Printer.

The Wincode driver will interpret text as actual output. Since you are creating the actual printer commands, you don't anything to interpret the commands other than the printer.

Once you set up the printer to use the generic text based driver, you can open notepad++ (or standard Windows notepad; remove the header and footer in the page setup) put some simple ZPL commands in there (`^XA^CF0,60^FO50,50^FDTest Label^FS^XZ`), and print a test label (using the new generic driver) to check if it's working.

Comment: i hv tried this tutorial to setup generic driver for my wincode printer. but it does nothing when i'm trying to print test page. https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-configure-RAW-printing-mode-in-Windows/

But i will try again later, to make sure nothing was missed. :)

Comment: Hi Ed, i have tried your suggestion : add new printer with generic/text only driver, open windows notepad, remove all margin, empty header footer, then copy your test command to print. But the printer didn't do anything. Looks like this printer didn't recognize generic text only driver. i'm new to this task, is it a common standard all printer should recognized raw command ? TIA

Comment: See http://file.wincode.tkidn.com/Manual/OperationManual/Doc_02C_ENG.pdf Looks as though there could be a setting in your printer that may be impacting this. check "Printer Command" is set to "Auto Detect" or "ZPL" setting. You will have to download their utility to check/configure it: http://www.wincodetek.com/service/l/78